# c# memory model, locking, and syncronization

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, shared-memory, memory-model

Does the c# memory model guarantee that a thread holding a lock is guaranteed to see all updates performed while any other thread previously held the same lock?

I have been reading the c# specification but cant seem to find the specifics on this.

Comment: Good relevant article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj863136.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, subject to certain restrictions.For details, the section you are looking for is 3.10.

Comment: Can you expand on that? Specifically, that section talks about execution ordering, but there do not seem to guarantees of visibility of side effects to other threads.

Comment: That section is about visibility of side effects, so I do not understand what you're asking me to clarify. A lock causes a full fence, if that's your concern.

Comment: @mikez Yeah it says that all critical sections will preserve the ordering of side effects that happen before them, then lists locks as a critical section.  
Thanks for pointing me to the right spot eric, couldnt find it to save my life :D

Answer (score 7):

Going for the intuitive explanation: if that guarantee wasn't provided then you couldn't implement a lock.

Going for the formal explanation: this is covered by the CLI spec (Ecma 335), chapter I.12.6.5:

> Acquiring a lock (System.Threading.Monitor.Enter or entering a synchronized method) shall
>   implicitly perform a volatile read operation, and releasing a lock
>   (System.Threading.Monitor.Exit or leaving a synchronized method) shall implicitly perform a
>   volatile write operation.
>
> A volatile read has “acquire semantics” meaning that the read is guaranteed to occur prior to any
>   references to memory that occur after the read instruction in the CIL instruction sequence. A
>   volatile write has “release semantics” meaning that the write is guaranteed to happen after any
>   memory references prior to the write instruction in the CIL instruction sequence.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent snippet, although I would argue that you could take a chance of reading stale data even with functional locks. It does occur the more I think about it though that if the data were stale you wouldn't know the lock was released.  Not sure if it would be possible for the lock to be not stale and some of the other side effects to be stale, that is the world of reordering though, crazy things happen :)

Answer (score 1):

Locking just pauses other threads that want the lock.  This guarantees that only one thread performs the update to the share data.

When, the lock is realeased, another thread can then update the data and it would see the previous thread's updates.

Comment: That's not all locks do.  They also introduce memory barriers, which is important.